# AS3: How can I shorten this if else statement?

Tags: actionscript

I'm new to AS3 so please forgive me if this is a silly question.

I'm trying to write an if else statement for something, and although its pretty long, it's only 1/5 of what I need. I definitely see a pattern in this, and I want to write a loop for it.

but I can't seem to get my head wrapped around it. Can someone please help me out?

```
if(all_mc.x<-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth+1) {
    mcPosX = 0;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*2+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*2-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*3+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*2;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*3-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*4+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*3;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*4-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*5+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*4;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*5-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*6+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*5;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*6-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*7+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*6;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*7-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*8+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*7;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*8-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*9+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*8;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*9-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*10+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*9;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*10-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*11+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*10;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*11-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*12+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*11;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*12-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*13+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*12;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*13-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*14+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*13;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*14-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*15+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*14;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*15-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*16+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*15;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*16-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*17+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*16;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*17-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*18+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*17;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*18-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*19+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*18;
} else if(all_mc.x<-panelWidth*19-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth*20+1) {
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*19;
}

//Tween all_mc to position
var toRightTween:TweenLite = new TweenLite(all_mc,0.5, {x:mcPosX});
```

`mcPosX` needs to go up to = -panelWidth*200!

Answer (score 0):

```
var i:int = 200;
if(all_mc.x<-1 && all_mc.x>-panelWidth+1) {
    mcPosX = 0;
} else{
    while(all_mc.x<(-panelWidth*i)-1 && all_mc.x>(-panelWidth*(i+1))+1) {
       i--;
    }
    mcPosX = -panelWidth*i;
}
```

There might be better solution for your problem i think, but this is ok for the part you post.

Comment: Hi ymutlu, thank you for your help. At the end of my codes there is a tween. Basically I'm trying to detect the position of the `all_mc` to tween it to the nearest `panelWidth`. When I tried your codes it seems to always tween to 0. My apologies if this is confusing.

Comment: edited the answer, i think this will help out. But if your "ifelse"s is working , this should work also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may make this question easier to answer if you explain what you are trying to achieve as opposed to trying to fix your implementation. I'm guessing that you can probably achieve your intended result using different logic altogether.